# PSCustomObject - Properties Not Present - Name and Value

Tags: powershell

I am re-working a colleagues PowerShell script (1000+ lines), and I have noted this odd behaviour:

```
[pscustomobject]$obj = @{"Colour" = "Blue"; "Car" = "Volkswagen"}

# Check the variable.
$obj     

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Car                            Volkswagen
Colour                         Blue
```

Using a different method:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{"Colour" = "Blue"; "Car" = "Volkswagen"}

# Check the variable.
$obj

Colour Car       
------ ---       
Blue   Volkswagen
```

The properties 'Name' and 'Value' are removed for the custom object. What is happening here?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what's going on in the first example. Casting to `[PSCustomObject]` only works when you apply it to the hashtable/dictionary directly. Applying it to a variable won't do anything, so `$obj` still just contains a regular hashtable, no different than if you'd done `$obj = @{"Colour" = "Blue"; "Car" = "Volkswagen"}`

Comment: As a side note to the explanation above, you don't need to quote property names: `[pscustomobject]@{Colour="Blue"; Car="Volkswagen"}`

Comment: @Scepticalist this is only half true. If your property name includes a space you must use quotes.